# R: How to use parallel computing on calculating trends in raster

Tags: r, parallel-processing, spatial, raster, trend

Recently I came across over this library in R [spatialEco](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/spatialEco/spatialEco.pdf). I want to calculate the Kendall tau statistic for a raster stack in R. However, this would take a lot of time since this library is using just one core on the computer (the raster I plan to use is at a global extent at 250 m resolution)

```
library(raster)
library(spatialEco)

r.logo <- stack(system.file("external/rlogo.grd", package="raster"),
system.file("external/rlogo.grd", package="raster"),
system.file("external/rlogo.grd", package="raster"))

# Calculate trend slope with p-value and confidence level(s)
start_time <- Sys.time()

logo.trend <- raster.kendall(r.logo, tau = TRUE, intercept = TRUE, p.value = TRUE,
z.value = TRUE, confidence = TRUE)

end_time <- Sys.time()
end_time - start_time

names(logo.trend) <- c("slope","tau", "intercept", "p.value", "z.value", "LCI", "UCI")
plot(logo.trend)
```

Is is possible to use a library like `library(parallel)` in order to calculate the trend on a raster stack? Is it necessary to convert the data to a matrix and then use these libraries?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`spatialEco::raster.kendall()` calls `raster::overlay()` and one can run that in parallel:

1. Get the relevant function from `spatialEco::raster.kendall()`:

   ```
   trend.slope <- function(y, p.value.pass = TRUE, z.pass = TRUE, 
                           tau.pass = TRUE, confidence.pass = TRUE, intercept.pass = TRUE) {
       options(warn = -1)
       fit <- EnvStats::kendallTrendTest(y ~ 1)
       fit.results <- fit$estimate[2]
       if (tau.pass == TRUE) {
           fit.results <- c(fit.results, fit$estimate[1])
       }
       if (intercept.pass == TRUE) {
           fit.results <- c(fit.results, fit$estimate[3])
       }
       if (p.value.pass == TRUE) {
           fit.results <- c(fit.results, fit$p.value)
       }
       if (z.pass == TRUE) {
           fit.results <- c(fit.results, fit$statistic)
       }
       if (confidence.pass == TRUE) {
           ci <- unlist(fit$interval["limits"])
           if (length(ci) == 2) {
               fit.results <- c(fit.results, ci)
           }
           else {
               fit.results <- c(fit.results, c(NA, NA))
           }
       }
       options(warn = 0)
       return(fit.results)
   }
   ```
2. Start a cluster with `n` nodes.

   ```
   beginCluster(n=2)
   ```
3. Do the calculations in parallel.

   ```
   logo.trend.parallel <- clusterR(r.logo, overlay, args=list(fun=trend.slope))
   ```
4. Stop cluster.

   ```
   endCluster()
   ```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a timed comparison.

Example data (a bit more fancy to avoid having all value being the same)

```
library(raster)
f <- system.file("external/rlogo.grd", package="raster")
s <- stack(f)+1
r.logo <- stack(s/2, s, s*2)
```

I am only computing Tau here. First with `raster.kendall`

```
library(spatialEco)
system.time(
 logo.trend1 <- raster.kendall(r.logo, tau=TRUE)
)
#   user  system elapsed 
#   6.73    0.00    6.72
```

Now, with `calc` and the base `cor` function

```
nl <- 1:nlayers(r.logo)
kfun <- function(i) {
 cor(nl, i, method="kendall")
}

system.time(
 logo.trend2 <- calc(r.logo, kfun)
)
#   user  system elapsed 
#   0.51    0.00    0.51
```

That is 13x faster. Now in parallel

```
beginCluster(n=4)
system.time(
 logo.trend.parallel <- clusterR(r.logo, calc, args=list(fun=kfun), export="nl")
)
#   user  system elapsed 
#   0.05    0.05    0.69 
endCluster()
```

No time gain, but that is expected with a small dataset, and could be different with a large dataset.